# RabbitMQ connection autorecovering after network fails

Tags: java, sockets, networking, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a problem when RabbitMQ attempts to recover connection after network interface fails.
I create connection to RMQ and emulate network interface fail (`sudo ifdown enp0s3` in Centos).

After requested heartbeat timeout I'm getting UnknownHostException. It's ok because I don't have in /etc/hosts RMQ address.

But when I start network interface (`sudo ifup enp0s3`) I'm getting this expeptions again and again. Connection doesn't recover after network interface fail.

Java version 1.8.0_60
amqp-client: 3.5.6

**Code:**

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    Connection conn = null;
    Channel channel = null;

    factory.setUsername(USERNAME);
    factory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    factory.setVirtualHost(VIRTUAL_HOST);
    factory.setHost(HOST);
    factory.setPort(PORT);
    factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(4);
    // auto-recovery
    factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(5000);

    try {
        conn = factory.newConnection();
        channel = conn.createChannel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(String.format("Connection is opened: %s", conn.isOpen()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Exception:**

> Caught an exception during connection recovery!
>
> java.net.UnknownHostException: rmq.dev    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:34)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverConnection(AutorecoveringConnection.java:476)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.beginAutomaticRecovery(AutorecoveringConnection.java:444)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.access$000(AutorecoveringConnection.java:53)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection$1.shutdownCompleted(AutorecoveringConnection.java:383)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:576)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Connection is opened: false,
>   channel is opened: false

Can anybody help me? Why Java can't resolve hostname after network fail?

Comment: Can you try with conn = factory.newConnection(); to create a new connection at the point of exception catch block

Comment: @maheeka Unfortunately, it doesn't have any effect because Exception is thrown from another AMQP Connection Thread.

Comment: I can just set connection Exception handler. In that method I'm getting connection and thrown exception but I can't reopen connection because it hasn't such method

Comment: Can you post the code that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem with RabbitMQ recovering fixes by periodical resolving `InetAddress.getByName(HOST)` outside Amqp-client. But I don't understand why this resolving can't work inside `InetSocketAddress` constructor.
Any ideas? Does exist any better solution?